# Link errors on MacOS High Sierra: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" std::__1

Tags: gcc, makefile, compiler-errors, g++, gfortran

I would like to play a bit with the code of MAD-X (Methodical Accelerator Design; http://madx.web.cern.ch/madx/). I must admit that I am a complete newbie to c, c++, compiling, etc.

I downloaded the sources from the Mad-X git repository (https://github.com/MethodicalAcceleratorDesign/MAD-X) to my MacBook pro (2016, Intel) and in a first step I wanted to compile the code without modifications. To do so, I run

```
make madx-macosx64-gnu
```

which runs through the compilation process with some warnings, but the linking fails with numerous errors:

```
*** Compiling madx_ptc_track_run.f90
*** Compiling madx_ptc_trackcavs.f90
*** Compiling ptc_export_xml.f90
*** Compiling St_pointers.f90
*** Compiling madx_ptc_twiss.f90
*** Compiling user2_photon.f90
*** Compiling madx_ptc_normal.f90
*** Compiling wrap.f90
*** Linking build/madx-macosx64-gnu
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::compare(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      SeqElList::sbend_from_rbend(element const*) in mad_mkthin.o
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      void std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >::__push_back_slow_path<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in mad_6track_name_mangler.o
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >::vector(unsigned long) in mad_mkthin.o
      void std::__1::vector<element*, std::__1::allocator<element*> >::__push_back_slow_path<element* const&>(element* const&) in mad_mkthin.o
      void std::__1::vector<OneElementWithSlices*, std::__1::allocator<OneElementWithSlices*> >::__push_back_slow_path<OneElementWithSlices* const&>(OneElementWithSlices* const&) in mad_mkthin.o
      void std::__1::vector<sequence*, std::__1::allocator<sequence*> >::__push_back_slow_path<sequence* const&>(sequence* const&) in mad_mkthin.o
  "std::__1::__basic_string_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      _NameMangler_mangle in mad_6track_name_mangler.o
      _NameMangler_demangle in mad_6track_name_mangler.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in mad_6track_name_mangler.o
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(char, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in mad_6track_name_mangler.o
      slice_sequence(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, sequence*) in mad_mkthin.o
      ElementListWithSlices::find_slice(element const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in mad_mkthin.o
      SeqElList::sbend_from_rbend(element const*) in mad_mkthin.o
      ...
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from
[...]
```

can you give me advice how to compile this? E.g., there are a couple of Makefiles, one for MacOS, but I'm not sure how to use them properly.

Based on Ulrich Eckhardt's comments I ran "`make -d --trace`", which provides a lot of output, but unfortunately nothing more conclusive on "Undefined symbols..."

```
MANY LINES BEFORE        
Pruning file 'Sl_family.o'.
        Pruning file 'So_fitting.o'.
        Pruning file 'm_real_polymorph.o'.
        Pruning file 'k_tpsalie_analysis.o'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'build/madx64'.
  Must remake target 'build/madx64'.
make/linker.rules:28: update target 'build/madx64' due to: mad_elem.o mad_plot.o mad_write.o mad_dict.o mad_elemerr.o mad_str.o mad_survey.o mad_macro.o mad_option.o mad_emit.o mad_name.o mad_beam.o mad_match.o mad_cmdpar.o mad_sdds.o mad_const.o mad_array.o mad_node.o mad_cmdin.o mad_aper.o mad_vec.o mad_track.o mad_gvar.o mad_parse.o mad_ibs.o mad_time.o mad_cmd.o mad_table.o mad_twiss.o mad_main.o mad_6track.o mad_spch.o mad_ptcknobs.o mad_core.o mad_mem.o mad_sxf.o mad_util.o mad_eval.o mad_ptc.o mad_gcst.o mad_stream.o mad_exec.o mad_var.o mad_touschek.o mad_gxx11c.o mad_orbit.o mad_expr.o mad_regex.o mad_api.o mad_dynap.o mad_seq.o mad_inter.o mad_sodd.o mad_match2.o mad_select.o mad_rand.o mad_err.o mad_range.o mad_synrad.o mad_rplot.o mad_mkthin.o mad_6track_name_mangler.o touschek.o wrap.o trrun.o matchjc.o matchlib.o twiss.o madx_ptc_module.o dynap.o emit.o madx_ptc_track_run.o gxx11.o madx_ptc_script.o ibsdb.o madx_ptc_normal.o match.o orbf.o plot.o madx_ptc_trackcavs.o survey.o user2_photon.o madx_ptc_knobs.o matchlib2.o matchsa.o madx_ptc_twiss.o sodd.o madx_ptc_distrib.o util.o resindex.o madx_ptc_setcavs.o madx_ptc_eplacement.o ptc_export_xml.o madx_ptc_intstate.o mad_inif_f.o Sc_euclidean.o cc_dabnew.o b_da_arrays_all.o Spb_fake_gino_sub.o Se_status.o Sb_sagan_pol_arbitrary.o Si_def_element.o Sm_tracking.o Sd_frame.o Sf_def_all_kinds.o Sp_keywords.o Sr_spin.o cb_da_arrays_all.o Sq_orbit_ptc.o St_pointers.o Sg_sagan_wiggler.o d_lielib.o Sma0_beam_beam_ptc.o Sn_mad_like.o c_dabnew_berz.o h_definition.o Ci_tpsa.o Sh_def_kind.o a_scratch_size.o Sra_fitting.o j_tpsalie.o Sa_extend_poly.o Sma_multiparticle.o n_complex_polymorph.o Sk_link_list.o l_complex_taylor.o c_dabnew.o o_tree_element.o i_tpsa.o Sl_family.o So_fitting.o m_real_polymorph.o k_tpsalie_analysis.o
echo "*** Linking build/madx64"
Putting child 0x7f93f354ff60 (build/madx64) PID 34699 on the chain.
Live child 0x7f93f354ff60 (build/madx64) PID 34699 
*** Linking build/madx64
Reaping winning child 0x7f93f354ff60 PID 34699 
gfortran -m64 -O3 -fmax-stack-var-size=65536 -Wl,-no_compact_unwind -Wl,-no_pie -o build/madx64 build/Darwin64/mad_elem.o build/Darwin64/mad_plot.o build/Darwin64/mad_write.o build/Darwin64/mad_dict.o build/Darwin64/mad_elemerr.o build/Darwin64/mad_str.o build/Darwin64/mad_survey.o build/Darwin64/mad_macro.o build/Darwin64/mad_option.o build/Darwin64/mad_emit.o build/Darwin64/mad_name.o build/Darwin64/mad_beam.o build/Darwin64/mad_match.o build/Darwin64/mad_cmdpar.o build/Darwin64/mad_sdds.o build/Darwin64/mad_const.o build/Darwin64/mad_array.o build/Darwin64/mad_node.o build/Darwin64/mad_cmdin.o build/Darwin64/mad_aper.o build/Darwin64/mad_vec.o build/Darwin64/mad_track.o build/Darwin64/mad_gvar.o build/Darwin64/mad_parse.o build/Darwin64/mad_ibs.o build/Darwin64/mad_time.o build/Darwin64/mad_cmd.o build/Darwin64/mad_table.o build/Darwin64/mad_twiss.o build/Darwin64/mad_main.o build/Darwin64/mad_6track.o build/Darwin64/mad_spch.o build/Darwin64/mad_ptcknobs.o build/Darwin64/mad_core.o build/Darwin64/mad_mem.o build/Darwin64/mad_sxf.o build/Darwin64/mad_util.o build/Darwin64/mad_eval.o build/Darwin64/mad_ptc.o build/Darwin64/mad_gcst.o build/Darwin64/mad_stream.o build/Darwin64/mad_exec.o build/Darwin64/mad_var.o build/Darwin64/mad_touschek.o build/Darwin64/mad_gxx11c.o build/Darwin64/mad_orbit.o build/Darwin64/mad_expr.o build/Darwin64/mad_regex.o build/Darwin64/mad_api.o build/Darwin64/mad_dynap.o build/Darwin64/mad_seq.o build/Darwin64/mad_inter.o build/Darwin64/mad_sodd.o build/Darwin64/mad_match2.o build/Darwin64/mad_select.o build/Darwin64/mad_rand.o build/Darwin64/mad_err.o build/Darwin64/mad_range.o build/Darwin64/mad_synrad.o build/Darwin64/mad_rplot.o build/Darwin64/mad_mkthin.o build/Darwin64/mad_6track_name_mangler.o build/Darwin64/touschek.o build/Darwin64/wrap.o build/Darwin64/trrun.o build/Darwin64/matchjc.o build/Darwin64/matchlib.o build/Darwin64/twiss.o build/Darwin64/madx_ptc_module.o build/Darwin64/dynap.o build/Darwin64/emit.o build/Darwin64/madx_ptc_track_run.o build/Darwin64/gxx11.o build/Darwin64/madx_ptc_script.o build/Darwin64/ibsdb.o build/Darwin64/madx_ptc_normal.o build/Darwin64/match.o build/Darwin64/orbf.o build/Darwin64/plot.o build/Darwin64/madx_ptc_trackcavs.o build/Darwin64/survey.o build/Darwin64/user2_photon.o build/Darwin64/madx_ptc_knobs.o build/Darwin64/matchlib2.o build/Darwin64/matchsa.o build/Darwin64/madx_ptc_twiss.o build/Darwin64/sodd.o build/Darwin64/madx_ptc_distrib.o build/Darwin64/util.o build/Darwin64/resindex.o build/Darwin64/madx_ptc_setcavs.o build/Darwin64/madx_ptc_eplacement.o build/Darwin64/ptc_export_xml.o build/Darwin64/madx_ptc_intstate.o build/Darwin64/mad_inif_f.o build/Darwin64/Sc_euclidean.o build/Darwin64/cc_dabnew.o build/Darwin64/b_da_arrays_all.o build/Darwin64/Spb_fake_gino_sub.o build/Darwin64/Se_status.o build/Darwin64/Sb_sagan_pol_arbitrary.o build/Darwin64/Si_def_element.o build/Darwin64/Sm_tracking.o build/Darwin64/Sd_frame.o build/Darwin64/Sf_def_all_kinds.o build/Darwin64/Sp_keywords.o build/Darwin64/Sr_spin.o build/Darwin64/cb_da_arrays_all.o build/Darwin64/Sq_orbit_ptc.o build/Darwin64/St_pointers.o build/Darwin64/Sg_sagan_wiggler.o build/Darwin64/d_lielib.o build/Darwin64/Sma0_beam_beam_ptc.o build/Darwin64/Sn_mad_like.o build/Darwin64/c_dabnew_berz.o build/Darwin64/h_definition.o build/Darwin64/Ci_tpsa.o build/Darwin64/Sh_def_kind.o build/Darwin64/a_scratch_size.o build/Darwin64/Sra_fitting.o build/Darwin64/j_tpsalie.o build/Darwin64/Sa_extend_poly.o build/Darwin64/Sma_multiparticle.o build/Darwin64/n_complex_polymorph.o build/Darwin64/Sk_link_list.o build/Darwin64/l_complex_taylor.o build/Darwin64/c_dabnew.o build/Darwin64/o_tree_element.o build/Darwin64/i_tpsa.o build/Darwin64/Sl_family.o build/Darwin64/So_fitting.o build/Darwin64/m_real_polymorph.o build/Darwin64/k_tpsalie_analysis.o -L/usr/X11/lib -lX11 -lstdc++ -lm
Live child 0x7f93f354ff60 (build/madx64) PID 34700 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::compare(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      SeqElList::sbend_from_rbend(element const*) in mad_mkthin.o
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >::vector(unsigned long) in mad_mkthin.o
      void std::__1::vector<element*, std::__1::allocator<element*> >::__push_back_slow_path<element* const&>(element* const&) in mad_mkthin.o
      void std::__1::vector<OneElementWithSlices*, std::__1::allocator<OneElementWithSlices*> >::__push_back_slow_path<OneElementWithSlices* const&>(OneElementWithSlices* const&) in mad_mkthin.o
      void std::__1::vector<sequence*, std::__1::allocator<sequence*> >::__push_back_slow_path<sequence* const&>(sequence* const&) in mad_mkthin.o
      void std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >::__push_back_slow_path<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in mad_6track_name_mangler.o
  "std::__1::__basic_string_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      slice_sequence(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, sequence*) in mad_mkthin.o
      ElementListWithSlices::find_slice(element const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in mad_mkthin.o
      SeqElList::sbend_from_rbend(element const*) in mad_mkthin.o
      my_dump_command(command const*) in mad_mkthin.o
      SeqElList::create_thick_slice(element*, int)  in mad_mkthin.o
      SeqElList::slice_this_node()      in mad_mkthin.o
      create_bend_dipedge_element(element*, bool) in mad_mkthin.o
[...]
```

Comment: I think that if you run `make` with `-v`, it gives you the actual commands that it executes, because that is important info. Anyhow, in short, the error means that some parts of the C++ standardlibrary can't be found.

Comment: Hi Ulrich, thanks for the hint. The "make -v" seems to be the "version" command. Based on your hint I ran make with option "-d" which produces a lot more output for the compilation, but the same output for linking :(

Comment: Try using `--trace`.

Comment: Nope: "make --trace" -> "unrecognized option" (gnu make version 3.81)

Comment: Version 4.1 has it in its manpage. Check your's, there must be an option to make `make` talk. ;)

Comment: Ok Updates make to 4.2.1, ran make -d --trace and added result to question

Comment: This is a comment because I see the problem but not the solution. The problem is the `-lstdc++` option to `gfortran`. That's the gnu c++ standard library. The missing references to things like `std::__1::basic_string` means that some of your code has been compiled to call the LLVM c++ standard library rather than the GNU c++ standard library. It's a very bad idea to mix and match those two standard libraries. Cats and dogs, living together, ...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174180/link-osx-homebrew-gfortran-against-libc

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [David Hammen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774499/david-hammen)'s comments and the link therein:

[Link OSX Homebrew Gfortran against libc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174180/link-osx-homebrew-gfortran-against-libc)

I was able to resolve this:

I searched for all occurrences of "-lstdc++" in the files and found hits in the following files:

- linker.g95 (no need to edit this...)
- linker.gfortran: change line 44 from

  LDLIBS  += $(if $(call eq,$(OSTYPE),Darwin),-lgfortran **-lstdc++** -lgcc
  -lgcc_eh -lSystem -nodefaultlibs,)

  to
- LDLIBS  += $(if $(call eq,$(OSTYPE),Darwin),-lgfortran **-lc++** -lgcc
  -lgcc_eh -lSystem -nodefaultlibs,)
- Makefile_lib: change lines 57 and 62 (in the if-clause checking for Darwin = MACOS) and replace -lstdc++ with -lc++ too

Works like a fly :)